# Check if specific element exists in firestore document array

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection named `'products'` and inside `'products'`, I have a `document` named `'W2TO2uQlQ3T2iEvxxom3'`
Inside this document, I have an `array` called `Products`.
Inside this array, I have many `mappings`. Inside `each map`, there are `several elements`.

Query: how to figure out if a specific element exists inside a mapping inside Products.
After that, I want to print every mapping that contains a specific element such as "id : v3IzhvjVHKhmFK16OvWnHs8wOjm2"

[image: Firestore Image]

Answer (score 0):

Something you can try is getting the document that contains the `products` array from Firestore. From the document’s [data](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentSnapshot-class.html#instance-methods) (which is a `Map<String, dynamic>` type), you can traverse to the `products` array. With the `where()` [method](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Iterable/where.html), you can then filter the array based on predicates such as having a specific ID. You can combine this with a `toList()` [method](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Stream/toList.html), so that all the matched mappings are grouped into a list.

```
  FirebaseFirestore firebase = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  firebase
  .collection("products")
  .doc("prodArrayDoc") // Document which contains the products array
  .get()
  .then((doc) {
    var prodList = doc.data()?["products"].where((x) => // Traversing the data of the document to the products array
      x?["category"] == "Electronics" // Predicate to filter the array by
    ).toList();

    print(prodList);
  });
```

I recreated your structure for this snippet, and my array had several mappings with the “Electronics” category, all of the matching ones are returned:

```
  [{id: testProduct2, name: phone, category: Electronics}, {category: Electronics, name : speakers, id: testProduct3}]
```

In case it’s possible for your use case, directly storing each product as a document inside the `products` collections will allow you to query in a more straightforward way, based on the FlutterFire [docs](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#querying).

Comment: In case this answer helped you, you can click on the checkmark icon to mark it as accepted. This can help future users who are having the same issue.